# Embed a webpage in Quarto html

Tags: html, embed, quarto, reveal.js

Is there a way to embed a webpage in a Quarto `reveal.js` or HTML output?

So far, there is [documentation](https://quarto.org/docs/presentations/revealjs/#iframe-backgrounds) for IFrames as interactive background for `reveal.js`, but this is not really flexible.

Reproducible example:

```
---
format: revealjs
---

## A title

I'd like to embed [this webpage](https://example.com/).
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a HTML block with `=html` to embed a webpage, and it's interactive. This works for both HTML and revealjs output.

````
---
format: revealjs
---

## A title

```{=html}
<iframe width="780" height="500" src="https://example.com/" title="Webpage example"></iframe>
```
````

[image]

Comment: If I embed the an interactive html with plots and tables in a quatro tabs, tab1 shows the interactive HTML. But, the Tab 2 does not display (plots or tables )  Do you know why ?